# Confusion about the Definition of Boiling Point

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

From the description of boiling [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling):

> Boiling is the rapid vaporization of a liquid, which occurs when a liquid is heated to its boiling point, the temperature at which the vapor pressure of the liquid is equal to the pressure exerted on the liquid by the surrounding environmental pressure.

What I do not understand is the last statement. Does this mean that by definition, boiling cannot occur if we have a homogeneous system (i.e. a closed container of liquid water at equilibrium with its vapor phase) since the definition requires an "atmosphere"? Should we still see the nucleation effect or "bubbles" even in the absence of atmosphere (like in a pressure controlled piston-cylinder assembly)? If so, what is the difference in phase transition between presence of atmosphere or no atmosphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition does not require an "atmosphere". Your "environment" can be vacuum. A liquid can boil in vacuum.

Comment: This is what I had thought, but if so how does the last sentence of the Wiki article fit in? Does the presence of an atmosphere have no effect on the boiling mechanism itself (i.e. we will still see nucleation/bbubles even under a pressure controlled homogeneous environment)?

Comment: @Yandle: The presence of atmosphere does have effect on the boiling mechanism, for example, through its pressure. I believe, however, that "we will still see nucleation/bbubles even under a pressure controlled homogeneous environment", as there are vapor bubbles (http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=3197 )

Comment: If I had a piston maintaining 1atm of pressure, how does the mechanism differ than if I boil a pot of water open to 1atm of air? Is there a reason why boiling typically implies the presence of an atmosphere?

Comment: @Yandle: I guess there can be more than one differing factor, but, in particular, the vapor pressure under the piston will always be saturated (in equilibrium).

Comment: @Yandle: I guess one "reason why boiling typically implies the presence of an atmosphere" is it is difficult (if not impossible) to achieve full vacuum.

Comment: 1. What if I do an experiment where the air is perfectly saturated as I slowly heat from some T to the boiling point, should I expect similar behaviour as if the air wasn't there? 2. I got confused by the full vacuum comment, what does it mean?

Comment: @Yandle: 1. I don't understand that - as far as I remember, there cannot be saturated air other than at very low temperatures. 2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high_vacuum

Comment: 1. By saturated air, I meant air at 100%RH; if I can maintain this up to the boiling point, does the air actually affect the boiling compared to if the air was not present? 2. I'm confused about how vacuum comes into play

Comment: @Yandle: 1. I see... maybe I am wrong, but I thought 100%RH means the water vapor is saturated. OK. then if you increase the temperature without adding some water, the vapor (or the air:-) ) becomes unsaturated. 2. If you have no atmosphere, you have vacuum (if we do not count water vapor). It is difficult to pump out all air.